# Access reference to another table

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, primary-key

Hi I'm not sure how to build an SQL query to access the PK/FK.

I'm trying work out a query to figure out which item in the `REPORT_RESULT` table is pointed from the `AS_REPORT.REPORT_STUDY` table. As per the attached screenshot, in SQL plus their Indexes and References are visible.

When I run a query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM as_report.report_study WHERE REPORT=111111;
```

I see no references to the `REPORT_RESULT` table.

Here is a screenshot showing what the database looks like in SQL Plus https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilaMY.png

Comment: Not everybody can access screenshots. You're more likely to get a helpful response if you post actual data here.

Comment: You need to join the tables using the foreign key relationship. You are only selecting from a single table. This is very, very basic. You need to consult a beginners course on writing SQL.